# Google Cloud Storage Space in free application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm new too google app engine platform and have created a new application through this usl `https://appengine.google.com/start/createapp`.
When I was reading about it i stumbled upon [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) which gave details about pricing options for google cloud storage.
But in the dashboard of the google app engine app in daily quota it shows me `5GB Google Cloud Storage Standard`  as seen below
[image: dashboard]

Would I have to pay for the daily 5GB quota? If not can I upload files from an app created in Java? After uploading a file, would it be deleted after a day, or will it remain their?

Please help since I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Default GCS Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Default_Gcs_Bucket) free quota is not daily, it's valid for as long as your app is active. You only have to pay once you exceed 5 GB (assuming you have billing enabled.)